# how to build c++ openGL project in xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

Im trying to create an openGL project in XCode 5 so that i can learn NeHe tutes on my mac.

Ive been following the steps at www.open.gl
Here are the steps i tried sofar..

- I homebrewed glfw3, glew and glm
- I made a new static C/C++ project.
- I made a main file.
- I added openGL framework.
- added `-framework openGL` compiler flag to main file.
- I added paths to brews to user searchpaths and made always search these.
- I included glfw in my main file and tried to run the code to open a window.
- Only glew files come up in lib, but the project builds&runs successfully but nothing happens.
- No errors either.

What am i missing here?

```
#include "main.h"

#include <glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
//    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
//    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); // Fullscreen

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the problem was but this tutorial made it simple (using cmake) and its working now:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/
This tutorial says that "Mac OS doesn’t support OpenGL 3.3. Recent Macs with MacOS 10.7 Lion and compatible GPUs can run OpenGL 3.2, but not 3.3" so that may very well have been my problem.